# PowerShell Get-MsolUser -TenantId equivalent in MS Graph API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am migrating from PowerShell script to MS Graph API. My PowerShell script used MSOnline module and worked great until a few weeks ago.

I have set up an app in **entra.microsoft.com** and works all right within the tenant where the app is registered but I bit confused as to how to pull data from clients we manage from this API.

Basically in PowerShell, I used to:

`Get-MsolPartnerContract -All` Which used to give me the tenant IDs of all the clients and

`Get-MsolUser -TenantId some-client-tenant-id -All` and it gives me users in that tenant.

In MS Graph API I can `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contracts` to pull tenant ids but not sure how to use the tenant ID to pull the users.

I couldn't locate the API endpoint that allows me to pull the users from that tenant.

Has anyone figured this out without having to create an app for each tenant? TA

Comment: I believe you need to request a new token for the TenantId you want to query. As far as I know, Graph APIs don't have an argument for TenantId, the TenantId is determined by the context and that is determined by when you request a token.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes I couldn't find the tenant id argument API.  But to request a new access token for the tenant ID means I have to register the new app in that tenant environment.  If so, this is exactly what I am trying to avoid as those tenants are linked to us as partners and I only want to manage one app. Bummer MS taking away that feature.